# Global coordinate system and universal covering space of AdS$_3$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topology, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

In the space $\mathbb{M}_{2}\times$ $\mathbb{M}_{2}$ with metric
    \begin{align}
    H_{AB}dX^{A}dX^{B} = - dX_{0}^{2} + dX_{1}^{2} + dX_{2}^{2} - dX_{3}^{2}, \label{9.2}
\end{align}
    AdS$_{3}$ is the hyperboloid
    \begin{align}
    X_{A}X^{A} = - \ell^{2}. \label{9.1}
\end{align}

---

One solution of this equation is
        \begin{align}
        X_{0} = \ell \cosh \rho \cos t,\qquad X_{1} = \ell \sinh \rho \sin \phi,\qquad X_{2} = \ell \sinh \rho \cos \phi,\qquad  X_{3} = \ell \cosh \rho \sin t. \label{9.3}
    \end{align}
        Then the induced metric on the hyperboloid AdS$_{3}$ is
        \begin{align}
        ds^{2} = \ell^{2}(-\cosh^{2}\rho\ dt^{2} + d\rho^{2} + \sinh^{2}\rho\ d\phi^{2}). \label{9.4}
    \end{align}

---

1. How do you know that this coordinate system is global? Should you look into geodesic completeness for an answer?

The extrinsic coordinate $t$ on the hyperboloid AdS$_{3}$ is periodic, whereas the intrinsic coordinate $t$ on the hyperboloid AdS$_{3}$ is 'unwrapped', $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$ the universal covering space of the hyperboloid).

2. Why would you not use $t \in (0,2\pi)$ and instead use $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$? Of course, the use of $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$ gives the same answer as the use of $t \in (0,2\pi)$, but you prefer $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$ because ... ... ... ?

Comment: The determinant of the metric is always nonzero.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your situation here - how can you be given both a manifold and a coordinate system and *not know* whether the coordinate system covers the whole manifold or not? What *exactly* is the data given here?

Comment: The data given here is the metric and I am supposed to find out if the coordinate system is global or not.

Comment: Let me edit my question.

Comment: @ 0celouvskyopoulos, the determinant of the metric in polar coordinates in flat Euclidean space is zero at $r=0$.

Comment: NB: $\mathrm{AdS}_3$ is topologically $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$, where $S^1$ is the time direction, if one defines it by the standard 'hyperboloid' embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$. Its universal cover involves turning this timelike circle into a line; in rough terms, the universal cover is the minimum 'extension' of the space necessary to get rid of non-contractible loops, like those that wind the circle a given number of times.

Comment: For 1, just check that your coordinates defines a smooth submersion to the submanifold defined by your $X^2 = -l$ equation. Becomes a diffeomorphism (to the target space deleting the image of l=0 by the looks of it) if you take $t \in S^1$, as you suggested.